Please explain the use of refetch in useQuery
I am trying to refetch data from an API using refetch. TuseQuery is what I am using. Can anyone give an example of how to use this?
const selectedDepartment = watch("department_id");
const { data: departments, isLoading: isLoadingDepartment, isError: isErrorDepartment } = DepartmentQuery();
const { data: doctors, isLoading: isLoadingDoctor, isError: isErrorDoctor, refetch:refetchDoctors } = getDoctorByDepartment(selectedDepartment);
const { mutate, isPending } = useAppointment();

useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedDepartment) {
        refetchDoctors();
    }
}, [selectedDepartment, refetchDoctors]);

I am expecting the doctor_id to be fetched everytime the department_id is changed. I have used a dropdown in my form.
